# Existing MODX lazy loading

Tags: optimization, lazy-loading, modx, modx-revolution

I have a website and customer want to optimize it a bit so, is there any easy ways to make it through MODX plugin or snippet?

I tried to do it manually but it always take a lot of time.

Found no ways in internet. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been facing the same issue until I have found a way to implement lazy loading to all iframes and images by:

1. Changing src to data-src for images and non-youtube iframes
2. Changing YouTube iframe to img and getting video thumbnail directly from YouTube

After that, I will initialize lazyload.js and execute some js.

You can find full example and the code in the repository [MODX-lazy-loader-snippet](https://github.com/andreyseregin/MODX-lazy-loader-snippet)

If you need any help, be free to comment on this answer and I will reply